# Jmeter: How to extract assertion results and use it for my API's

Tags: jmeter

My test plan looks like,

1. I am running some Http requests with assertion .
2. I need to check assertion is passed or failed (any built-in variable is available?) .
3. Need to call/extract assertion result and use it for my next API .

Any one help me on this.

Comment: So, How I can pass the test results to my API's after Jmeter Run? Please let me know

Comment: You can add assertion results in your test plan.

Comment: How I can add assertion results to your test plan?

Comment: Right click > Add > Assertion Results. Enter file name which will write the assertion results. Using csv read function, you can read the values and pass it on the subsequent requests.

Comment: I tried the above steps, but Jmeter writes the assertion results only after test  run complete, so I am getting <EOF> when I read from assertion results file using CSV read,  Is any other alertnate ways please let me know?

Comment: You will get only failure message in the Assertions results. If it pass, you will get response message as 'OK'

Comment: Also you can use this code `if (Boolean.valueOf(vars.get("DEBUG"))) {
  for (a: SampleResult.getAssertionResults()) {
    if (a.isError() || a.isFailure()) {
      log.error(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": "+SampleLabel+": Assertion failed for response: " + new String((byte[]) ResponseData));
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this case using BeanShell Listener by adding the following code and you can call assertion result on jmeter like ${results}

```
try 
{
int results;

    if (sampleResult.isSuccessful()) {
    log.info("Response Assertion PASSED");
    results = 1;
    vars.put("results","1");} 

else {
    log.info("Response Assertion FAILED" );
     results = 2;
    vars.put("results","2");}

}

catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) where you can get parent sampler [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) instance(s) and extract the required information from it like:

```
def assertionResult = SampleResult.getAssertionResults()[0]
if (assertionResult.isFailure()) {
    log.info("Assertion " + assertionResult.getName() + " failed")
    log.info(assertionResult.getFailureMessage())
}
```

Demo:

[image: JSR223 Assertion - previous assertions]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on using assertions. Also avoid using Beanshell as it may cause performance problems, if you need to go for scripting - stick to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Answer (score 0):

1.Use "Regular Expression Extractor" to extract assertion result.
2.Use BeanShell Sampler to get assertion result,then,use it for your next API.